# RxJS Microservice-Architecture: Request API only once instead of X-times for each component

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have a microservice-oriented frontend (angular-based) where every independend component calls the same search-api with the same string. Now, this leads to data duplication in the frontend. I have a centralized facade where i can inject a singleton. Is it possible that i return the observable to each service while the observable is not finished and in the end, i request the Backend with the search query only one time instead of X-times (x number of independend components)?

Situation:

```
>Search Term
----->Component X do Search --> asks API
----->Component Y do Search --> asks API
----->Component Z do Search --> asks API
```

What i want to achive:

```
>Search Term
----->Component X do Search --> asks API
----->Component Y do Search --> get same Observable
----->Component Z do Search --> get same Observable
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: One quick workaround would be cache the result in the singleton and return that result every time you request the observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call the API once and use the same observable in multiple places using publishReplay and refCount.

Check this example

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/fastest-way-to-cache-for-lazy-developers-angular-with-rxjs-444a198ed6a6

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you sir!